# Display User Personal Bar

Tags: liferay

I've created a user role, which doesn't inherit permissions from `Guest`. I've achieved it through `portal-ext.properties` with `permissions.check.guest.enabled=false` param. But now, if I logged in with this new user role, I can't log out, since I can see the `User Personal Bar` (probably  because of some permission settings). Any idea how to enable the `User Personal Bar` for my custom user role? I'm using Liferay 7.1 CE.

Comment: Do you have a custom portal theme? I also added `permissions.check.guest.enabled=false` and created a simple role, but I am able to logout using the DXP sidebar.

Comment: But having a 7.1 EE Fixpack3